# Supplier's DLL is is stated. Need to "instantiate" DllImport'ed methods

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport

I'm using DLL files from a supplier in my software using `DllImport` like:

```
[DllImport("Supplier.dll", EntryPoint = "AllocateHandle")]
private static extern bool AllocateHandle(out uint handle, string connectionDetails);

[DllImport("Supplier.dll", EntryPoint = "DeallocateHandle")]
private static extern bool DeallocateHandle(uint handle);

...
```

With the `AllocateHandle` method, I can retrieve a handle by giving connection details. I can then use that handle to call methods on a remote machine I am connected to. `DeallocateHandle` de-allocates this handle. The supplier says this is nessecary.

We found it's possible to retrieve multiple handles using the same connection details. (e.g. `AllocateHandle("10.1.1.1"); AllocateHandle("10.1.1.1");`) That works. Only, we cannot retrieve a handle with different connection details if a handle already exists. (e.g. `AllocHandle("10.1.1.1"); AllocateHandle("10.1.1.2");`).

However, when I do this, it works:

```
[DllImport("Supplier.dll", EntryPoint = "AllocateHandle")]
private static extern bool AllocateHandle(out uint handle, string connectionDetails);

[DllImport("Supplier2.dll", EntryPoint = "AllocateHandle")]
private static extern bool AllocateHandle2(out uint handle, string connectionDetails);
```

`AllocateHandle("10.1.1.1"); AllocateHandle2("10.1.1.2");`

But then we would have to re-compile whenever we need more connections.

Is there a way to achieve this without needing to duplicate the DLL file?

Comment: You kinda try to bypass the restrictions the supplier implemented in their library (probably because there were some reasons for that).

Comment: I think this is something the supplier of the DLL would have to answer.

Comment: I'm asking if it's possible in C# to load multiple versions of a DLL. This is not an intentional restriction of the vendor.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to load multiple versions of a DLL, but they must be [loaded into](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-load-assemblies-into-an-application-domain) different [application domains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/application-domains).

Comment: @Matthew Not for unmanaged DLLs

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Oh yes, of course!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load multiple instances of the same unmanaged library into a process, but they must be loaded with different filenames. In your scenario that probably means making copies of the DLL with temporary filenames each time you need a new instance.